# Was Osama Bin Laden Dead Since 2002?

Tags: history, united-states, osama-bin-laden

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fpBPVkpmoeg&feature=related

The above video claims that Osama was killed a while back, and that all the tapes released since then are fakes by the US Govt. Is there any truth to either of those claims?

Comment: Please avoid tags like conspiracy, conspiracy-theory, urban-legend... Thanks. :-)

Comment: Hrm.  Seems like Bush would've wanted to have brought him out to distract against the financial meltdown, if this were true.  Also, the guy is referencing himself and newsmax, two sources I really don't give much credence to.

Comment: @mmr, another question that comes to mind after reading your comment is, if what that guy says is true, what would the political motive be for bringing it out NOW?

Comment: @picakhu-- exactly.  It's the worst possible timing for an attempt at electioneering (as GHWBush found out with Gulf War I).  But I'm still curious to see any particular debunking rather than just a 'sniff test' rejection.

Comment: @mmr, it can also be argued that it was for some political reason afterall. I mean if they knew where he was hiding, and he had no idea they knew, then, they could have waited for a better timing. (i.e. closer to the political season.) (they-us govt, he-UBL)

Answer (score 6):

Osama bin Laden has been killed on May 2<sup>nd</sup>, 2011. This fact is undisputed by any relevant party:

> Osama bin Laden, then head of the Islamist militant group al-Qaeda, was killed in Pakistan on Monday, May 2, 2011, shortly after 1 a.m. local time by DEVGRU/SEAL Team 6, a United States special operations military unit.

[...]

> Al-Qaeda confirmed the death on May 6 with posts made on militant websites, vowing to avenge the killing.

—[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_of_Osama_bin_Laden)

Comment: Is Wikipedia *really* a good source?

Comment: @ike The fact that Al Qaeda confirms it does lend some weight.

Comment: @Shadur So they should link to those *"posts made on militant websites"*, rather than Wikipedia.